# Infinite loop nested within a block in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration, block

Here's what I'm trying to do. I'm iterating through an array of strings, each of which may contain `[]` multiple times. I want to use `String#match` as many times as necessary to process every occurrence. So I have an Array#each block, and nested within that is an infinite loop that should break only when I run out of matches for a given string.

```
def follow(c, dir)
  case c
    when "\\"
        dir.rotate!
    when "/"
        dir.rotate!.map! {|x| -x}
  end
  return dir
end

def parse(ar)
  ar.each_with_index { |s, i|
  idx = 0
  while true do
    t = s.match(/\[[ ]*([a-zA-Z]+)[ ]*\]/) { |m|
      idx = m.end 0
      r = m[1]
      s[m.begin(0)...idx] = " "*m[0].size
      a = [i, idx]
      dir = [0, 1]
      c = ar[a[0]][a[1]]
      while !c.nil? do
        dir = follow c, dir
        ar[a[0]][a[1]] = " "
        a[0] += dir[0]; a[1] += dir[1]
        c = ar[a[0]][a[1]]
        if c == ">" then
          ar[a[0]][a[1]+1] = r; c=nil
        elsif c == "<" then
          ar[a[0]][a[1]-r.size] = r; c=nil
        end
      end
      ar[a[0]][a[1]] = " "
      puts ar
   }
   if t == nil then break; end
   end
}
parse File.new("test", "r").to_a
```

Contents of test:

```
   +--------+----------+-------------+
   | Colors |  Foods   |  Countries  |
   +--------+----------+-------------+
   | red    | pizza    | Switzerland |
 /-->     /---->       |             |
 | |[kale]/ | hot dogs | Brazil      |
 | |     <----------------------\    |
 | | orange |[yellow]\ | [green]/    |
 | +--------+--------|-+-------------+
 \-------------------/
```

Goal:

```
   +--------+----------+-------------+
   | Colors |  Foods   |  Countries  |
   +--------+----------+-------------+
   | red    | pizza    | Switzerland |
     yellow   kale     |             |
   |        | hot dogs | Brazil      |
   | green                           |
   | orange |          |             |
   +--------+-------- -+-------------+
```

Actual output of program:

```
   +--------+----------+-------------+
   | Colors |  Foods   |  Countries  |
   +--------+----------+-------------+
   | red    | pizza    | Switzerland |
     yellow          kale      |             |
   |        | hot dogs | Brazil      |
   |     <----------------------\    |
   | orange |          | [green]/    |
   +--------+-------- -+-------------+
```

(Since the array is modified in place, I figure there is no need to update the match index.) The inner loop *should* run again for each pair of `[]` I find, but instead I only get one turn per array entry. (It seems that the `t=match...` bit isn't the problem, but I could be wrong.) How can I fix this?

Comment: Your code is quite difficult to read. Could you share a sample of input and the expected result?

Comment: @Martin Okay, I've added a test case, expected output, and actual output. If it helps, this is an entry for a [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37753/reorganize-by-arrows).

Comment: Ok, the code golf explains it a bit (short variable names, very terse code).